# jQuery - on('click') event doesn't work on dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="listaAtributos" class="editable isAtribute">
      <li>Atributo 1<i class="js-remove">✖</i></li>
      <li>Atributo 2<i class="js-remove">✖</i></li>
      <li>Atributo 3<i class="js-remove">✖</i></li>
    </ul>

$('#listaAtributos').append('<li>Atributo<i class="js-remove">✖</i></li>')

$('.js-remove').on('click', 'js-remove', function(){
$(this).parent().remove() })
```

this code doesn't work, someone tell me why?

Comment: Use like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/p8wnrkg5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind event to the parent element which has already been present on the dom

```
$('#listaMetodos').on('click', '.js-remove', function(){
```

Comment: $('#listaAtributos').append('<li>Atributo<i class="js-remove">✖</i></li>') yet doesn't work

Comment: what is not working? appending or removing?